# How to other write file using gawk script?

Tags: batch-file, csv, awk, overwrite, gawk

I have written one code for remove duplicates from CSV file & now i want to save file with its original name. I dont want to save as with different name. Below is the batch script :

## Code :

```
@echo off

C:\sw\awk\bin\gawk.exe "!x[$0]++" *.csv > "{print FILENAME, $0 > FILENAME ".csv"}" file*
```

My Objective is : I want to build dynamic batch script which will run on any CSV file. There should not be any type of dependency(file name).

```
Error is :
The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Please help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: need a better description than "it is not working" Do you get any error messages? Any other output? Do the output files you epxect get created, etc, etc. Please edit your question  using the `{}` tool at the top left of the edit box on high-lighted text.DONT post this info as a comment! (please!)  Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This batch file is trying to redirect output from `gawk` into a file called `{print FILENAME, $0 > FILENAME`, which is not a valid filename.

At present, the `gawk` code produces a single output that omits all duplicate lines in all of the CSV files in the directory.

If you want to omit duplicate lines from each CSV file individually and write each file out individually, you will need a loop in the batch file to present each CSV file to the `gawk` script individually and output each modified file individually. You can do that as follows (presuming `tmp.tmp` is not an existing file in the folder):

```
for %%f in (*.csv) do (
  gawk.exe "!x[$0]++" "%%f" >tmp.tmp
  copy tmp.tmp "%%f"
)
del tmp.tmp
```

As a cautionary note, on DOS or Windows if you write through standard output to a file that you are reading, you can overwrite the file that you are reading before you've finished reading it. That is why the code above writes to a temporary file and then copies the temporary file to the original file.

Comment: I also got this idea earlier but i dont know how to store file name in variable & then use that variable in output name.

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide an example of how to store the file name in the variable, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with your attempt. Firstly, you cannot write to the same file that you're reading from (at least, not while you're reading from it). Secondly, you're using the `awk` special variable `FILENAME` outside of the `awk` script, where it doesn't exist.

The following may work for a single file at a time. It reads the entire file in, using the line as the key of an associative array and using the line number as the value. Then in the `END` block, it prints the array out in order of the values, writing to the file it just read.

```
gawk "!($0 in a) {a[$0] = NR} END {PROCINFO[\"sorted_in\"]=\"@val_num_asc\"; for(x in a) print x >FILENAME}"
```